# <v-img> doesn`t work with static image. [Vuetify] Image load failed src: @/assets/img/logo.png

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I have simple vuetify image tag which has to load image file from project directory, but it never works

```
<v-img src="@/assets/img/logo.png"></v-img>
```

Vue cannot load image neither with relative path, nor with absolute. src with @ and require() also don`t work. When i try to require() image, compiler fails and says

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/logo.png' in 'D:\Projects\ExpertRestRELEASE\src\main\resources\static\js\pages'
```

It seems like a webpack problem, but i don`t have any idea how to solve it

Project structure:

[image]

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'js', 'main.js'),
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        disableHostCheck: true,
        compress: true,
        port: 8000,
        allowedHosts: [
            'localhost:9000'
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?\S*)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'js'),
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ],
    }
}
```

P.S url links work fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to request `/assets` which doesn't exist in your project, you only have `/assets.img` in there, so why are you requesting `/assets/img/logo.png` instead of `/assets.img/logo.png`? And why did you name this folder like this? You should probably rename it to just `assets`.

Also, there's another thing, look at the error, it tells you that it cannot find folder `/assets` inside `/src/main/resources/static/js/pages` because that `/assets` you're trying to get is 3 levels up, inside the `/resources`, not inside `/pages`

Try this:

```
<v-img :src="logoPath"></v-img>

...
data() {
  return {
    logoPath: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources', 'assets', 'logo.png')
  }
}
```

You can also try these:

```
<v-img src="./src/main/resources/assets/logo.png"></v-img>
<v-img src="./resources/assets/logo.png"></v-img>
<v-img src="./assets/logo.png"></v-img>
<v-img :src="__dirname + '/src/main/resources/assets/logo.png'"></v-img>
<v-img :src="__dirname + 'src/main/resources/assets/logo.png'"></v-img>
<v-img :src="__static + '/assets/logo.png'"></v-img>
<v-img :src="__static + 'assets/logo.png'"></v-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<v-img :src=require("@/assets/img/logo.png")></v-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.

```
<template>
    <v-img height="450" :src='gif' />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import gif from '@/assets/gifs/success_gif_1.gif'
</script>
```